# Relay driver ULN2803ADWR not able to drive new relay NA5W-K

Tags: arduino, relay

I am using an Arduino Nano to drive 24 relays through three [ULN2803ADWR](https://mm.digikey.com/Volume0/opasdata/d220001/medias/docus/874/ULN2803A_Rev2015.pdf) chips. Each output of the 74HC595 is connected to the input of the ULN2803ADWR , which drives a specific relay.

I initially used the [G6DN-1A-SL-5VDC](https://omronfs.omron.com/en_US/ecb/products/pdf/en-g6dn.pdf) relay, and my Arduino was able to drive each relay successfully. However, when I switched to the [NA5W-K](https://www.fcl.fujitsu.com/downloads/MICRO/fcai/relays/na.pdf) relay, the output of the ULN2803ADWR dropped to 0.6V, which was insufficient to drive the relay.

I have measured that the Arduino output is 5.0V, the input of the 74HC595 is also 5V, and the output of 74HC595 and input of the ULN2803ADWR is 5.0V. What could be the possible reasons for the voltage drops that cause the failure to drive the relays? Maybe the new relay requires more current? Do I need to amplify the output signals of the ULN2803ADWR or use ULN2003A (or other IC that can directly drive the new relay) instead?

Comment: You really have to show a schematic. But, in principle, the ULN2803 is a low side driver. That is, one pole of the relay coil has to be connected to +5.0v and the other to a ULN2803 pin. The logic is inverted. When the ULN2803 pin is LOW, the relay is activated.

Comment: The ULN2803 utilizes Darlington pairs as its output driver. These won’t pull down really low. Maybe use a TPIC6B595 as these have mosfet outputs and will pull lower in most cases. Or use discrete mosfets.

Comment: @Kartman The Must operate voltage (V) is 3.5 V for the G6DN-1A-SL-5VDC relay and 3.75 V for the NA5W-K relay. With a 5 V supply and a ULN2803 max Vce of 1.1 V (coil current is less than 30 mA and assuming the Arduino output causes the ULN2803 to saturate) I think both types of relays should have sufficient voltage across their coils to operate.

Comment: @Harry From the datasheets, the original relay G6DN-1A-SL-5VDC (General purpose coil) has a power consumption of approx 110 mW, and the new relay NA5W-K (Standard Type coil) has a Rated Power of 140 mW. What is current rating of the 5 V supply used?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.